# Find/replace in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, replace, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to find and replace text for Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code. I can do it for a specific cell by clicking to that cell and pressing Ctrl+H. But I cannot find a way to do it for all the cells in the entire notebook.

This is how it looks like when I press Ctrl+H for specific cells:
[image: Ctrl+H for specific cells]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue no longer exists in Visual Studio Code as of Version 1.59.1. You can use `Ctrl + H` to find/replace in the whole Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: What if we want to only find/replace in a text selection (or code chunk)? I can't figure out how to do that in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Answering myself: F3 will open up a chunk-specific search ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109147/3174566)). I'm still not sure how to [search only a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433910/missing-find-in-selection-in-vs-code-when-editing-jupyter-notebooks), though.

Answer (score 10):

1. You could click the search icon or use the shortcut key "`Ctrl+Shift+H`" to enter the search bar:

   [image]
2. Input search content, replace content, and need/exclude files to be searched:

   [image]
3. Click the "`Replace All`" button next to "Replace" (the position circled in the screenshot) to replace, then reopen the file:

   [image]

Comment: This apparently works only if you have the folder the notebook is in opened in vscode. If you just opened that notebook from your file manager, vscode can't find it to search it, so you have to open that folder first, which closes the whole editor with everything you've got opened and you have to restart your notebook. Very annoying.

Comment: Also, be very careful with just clicking on replace! It also finds all occurrences of the term in the underlying JSON. Found out about that when trying to replace my `v3` variable, and it found all the embedded `Matplotlib v3.3…` in the plots!

Comment: @JC_CL -It is recommended that you create a new thread and describe the problem you encounter in detail so that more people can view it and give a suitable solution.

Comment: It's not a problem that I need help with, I just figured I'd add these two pointers here, since the whole process is not exactly straightforward.

Comment: This is cumbersome. I just want to find & replace for the current file. A basic feature.