# Missing 'Find in Selection' in VS Code when editing Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, data-science

The 'find in selection' button is missing from VSCode when working with Jupyter Notebooks. It slows down development so I would like to ask if anybody knows how to activate it?

First image shows the search/replace when in a python file. Second image shows the missing button when in a notebook.

Python file:

[image: python file with 'find in selection' functionality]

Jypyter Notebook:

[image: Jupyter Notebook / 'find in selection' is missing]

Comment: I don't think it has that functionality yet, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121218.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan 2022, within a cell in a jupyternotebook you can search and replace in selection when pushing `F3`. As comment before, this function is not available when using Ctrl + H

More info :

- [How to find and replace text in a single cell when using Jupyter extension inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71319929/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-single-cell-when-using-jupyter-extension-insid/73109147#73109147)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141493
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121218

Answer (score 0):

The .ipynb file is written by a kind of markdown.
The only way is to rightclick the tab and reopen .ipynb by builtin text editor for now.

Comment: the backing format is JSON- not markdown.